# Why do most experienced programmers prefer to use dark themes for their IDE?

Tags: visual-studio

I have noticed that most experienced developers use dark theme. what is the reason behind that?

If it is the preference for most people why Visual Studio's default theme is light then?

Comment: For me it's just that after hours on the Pc the low brightness strains my eyes less.

Comment: I love the dark theme, especially when you have been staring at it for a while and your eyes have completely adjusted, then suddenly some unthemed dialog pops up and blasts my eyes with full bright whiteness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that it is easier on the eyes to look at a darker screen for long periods of time than it is on a lighter screen.  A white screen can be a real strain after a few hours.

I am definitely one of these dark theme users you speak of.  Other devs may have different reasons, but I do it to give my eyes some relief.  It would be interesting to hear of any other reasons people may use dark themes.